Unable to import CSV file
I want to fetch all data from the local CSV file. Please check my code.
import DATA from './dictionaries/en.csv';
const response = await fetch(DATA, {
      headers : { 
        'content-type': 'text/csv;charset=UTF-8'
       }
      })
      .catch(function() {
        console.log("error");
       }); 
      
      
const data = await response.text();


directly importing csv files will not work in nextjs. need to specify the path to the file importing. next will consider imported files as a js module. since csv files is not a js module it will not work.
const response = await fetch('/dictionaries/en.csv', {
      headers : { 
        'content-type': 'text/csv;charset=UTF-8'
       }
      })
      .catch(function() {
        console.log("error");
       }); 
      
      
const data = await response.text();

